# AudioRecord calculate amplitude

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm developing app for Speech to Text.

All is working great, but I would like to implement feedback when user is talking to the app to detect (pulsate) sound activity. Like Shazam app.
I think that I need to calculate amplitude then based on level of Amplitude to make pulsating animation.

This is code where I read bytes. I need how to calculate it using int that I get from the `read` method from `AudioRecord`.

```
   // stream bytes as they become available in chunks equal to the buffer size
        mAudioExecutor!!.scheduleAtFixedRate({
            // read audio data
            val read = mAudioRecorder!!.read(
                    mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.size, AudioRecord.READ_BLOCKING)

            // send next chunk
            if (read > 0) {
                subscriber(ByteString.copyFrom(mBuffer, 0, read))
            }
        }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **FFT (Fourier Transformation)** to get **amplitude** from the audio bytes.

You need to add couple of code to make this work:

As Stackoverflow has limit of 30,000 characters for answers. I cannot add code here. But I'm sharing my github gist to help you out.

**[Here](https://gist.github.com/BirjuVachhani/026279ccdf1fb3851fb1fb429bf457a0) is the link of my gist.**

There's 3 files that needs to be added to your source.

1. AudioCalculator.kt
2. FrequencyCalculator.kt
3. RealDoubleFFT.kt

**Usage:**

After adding above mentioned 3 files to your source code:

```
val audioCalculator = AudioCalculator()
// stream bytes as they become available in chunks equal to the buffer size
mAudioExecutor?.scheduleAtFixedRate({
    // read audio data
    val read = mAudioRecorder!!.read(
        mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.size, AudioRecord.READ_BLOCKING
    )

    // send next chunk
    if (read > 0) {
        val amplitude = audioCalculator.getAmplitude(mBuffer)
        // here you get amplitude
        subscriber(ByteString.copyFrom(mBuffer, 0, read))
    }
}, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```